# Exercise on Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Prove, or give an explicit counterexample to refute, the following assertion: if $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain, then $\{X_n^2\}$ is also a Markov chain.

It's easy to show that 
$$P\{X_{n+1}^2=j^2|X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{n}=i_n\}=P\{X_{n+1}^2=j^2|X_n=i_n\}$$
thus I think if I can also show that
$$P\{X_{n+1}^2=j^2|X_0=\{\pm i_0\},\ldots,X_n=\{\pm i_n\}\}=P\{X_{n+1}^2|X_n=\{\pm i_n\}\}$$
then this problem is done. But it seems incorrect. So now I have no idea how to proof it.

(Additional question: What properties should $f(x)$ satisfies to make $\{f(X_n)\}$ a Markov chain?)

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample consider the Markov chain $\{X_n\}$ described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27507/transformation-on-state-space-that-preserves-markov-property/27538#27538) by [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did). Assume everything to be the same as in the example, but instead of states $0, 1$ and $2$ consider the states $-1, 1$ and $2$.

Now the function $g(x)=x^2$ lumps together states $-1$ and $1$. That is, we have that $g(-1)=g(1)=1$ and $g(2)=4$, exactly as described in the aforementioned example. Then you have directly from the result that is proved there, that the process $g(X_n)=X_n^2$ does not have the markov property.

Concerning your additional question, you can read this [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379505000789) or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27507/transformation-on-state-space-that-preserves-markov-property) for more details.