# $ (X_n : n = 0, 1, 2, ...) $ is a Markov chain with state space $(1,2,...,10)$.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

$ (X_n : n = 0, 1, 2, ...) $ is a Markov chain with state space $(1,2,...,10)$. Then which of the following is the correct answer?

1. ($X_n+X_{n-1} : n = 1, 2, ...$) is a Markov chain.
2. ($X_n-X_{n-1} : n = 1, 2, ...$) is a Markov chain.
3. ($X_nX_{n-1} : n = 1, 2, ...$) is a Markov chain.
4. ($\frac {X_n}{X_{n-1}} : n = 1, 2, ...$) is a Markov chain.
5. None of the above is correct.

Is it option 5 is the correct answer because we cannot do the inverse of the function? Just like option 1, we asuume $X_n=4$ and $X_{n-1}=6$, then $X_n+X_{n-1}=10$, but we cannot do the inverse.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27507/transformation-of-state-space-that-preserves-markov-property

Comment: is it mean that my explanation of this problem is correct since the function are not one-to-one??